# cover up flaking antique bronze plating on curtain rod

Tags: metal, cover

We have metal curtain rods that are antique bronze colored and some of the plating is flaking off. Is there a way to cover up the flaking? I"m thinking maybe something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ARBEZM)? Or maybe some sort of spray paint? It needs to be somewhat tough because the when we open/close the curtains, the rings rub against the rod.

Comment: Check out the price of a replacement rod.  You could spend more trying to fix it (and another finish you apply probably won't be as durable as the factory finish).  If it has cheap "plating" that is peeling off, there isn't a good solution that will hold up and look original.